# android SQLite : how to search string in like if string contains ' symbol

Tags: android, sqlite

following is my query that I am trying to search name contain special character e.g. ' symbol

```
 SELECT * from  distributor where name like'%jeni's%'
```

when I tried to add backslash if work in MySQL but wont work in SQLite database
 I also tried following query

`SELECT * from  distributor where name like'%jeni\'s%'` 
can someone help me to how can i search if string contains ' symbol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try:

```
SELECT * from  distributor where name like'%jeni''s%'
```

**Working solution:**

Escape single quotes in statement like this:

```
String statement = statement.replace("'", "''")
```

Comment: i also tried these but not working SELECT  name from  distributor where name  like'%jeni"%'

Comment: Otherwise replace this character in String. `String statement = statement.replace("'", "''")`

Comment: thank u for answer it work for   searchText=searchText.replace("'","\''");